# sending gmail into admin's gmail from localhost

Tags: php

I want to send mail from localhost to my gmail account.I set all setting for use smtp server in php.ini and sendmail.ini.When I send data , all is  okay but I didn't receive any incoming message.How can I do that ?Please help me.

**Here is my code mail.php**

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
    Email address:
    <input name="email" type="text" />
    <br /> Name:
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <br /> Message:
    <br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**here is sendmail.php**

```
<?php
    echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
    $email_to = "khinthidaphyo92@gmail.com";
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email_from = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $email_subject = "Feedback from website";
    $headers = "From: " . $email_from . "\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\n";
    $message = "Name: ". $name . "\r\nMessage: " . $message;
    ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
    $sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f" .$email_from);
    echo $sent;
    echo "sent mail is" .$sent;
    if ($sent)
    {
        echo "It has been sent";
    } else {
        echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what server you are using in localhost to send mail?

Answer (score 0):

What is your system? Windows? use [sendmail](https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/) for windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your localhost to send emails directly, mail probably ends up in Google's spam filters. Easiest option is to use local mailer only to forward emails to gmail servers which then do the actual mailing. This way google won't consider you as a spammer.

There is an article about this at  https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay how to Configure Gmail as a Sendmail email relay.

Even easier is to use your internet service providers smtp server, which usually does not even require authentication while connecting from their network.